# Android WebView selected textEvent

Tags: android, webview

I have to implement HighLight text logic:

[image]

But I have no ideas how to do this (I am talking not about Quick ActionBar), I don't know what event I have to check to show this bar.

And I don't know  how I can get the selected HTML from this Webview to save it into the  file.